# mobile page change return to particular location in page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

```
$.mobile.changePage($("#apage#alocationinpage"));
```

I'm exploring a responsive web design technique in which on small devices you scroll down a big page but on bigger screens sections of the page float into 2 or 3 columns.

So when I do something like return from a dialog I want to go back to a location that can be way down the page. I was thinking I could use some version of

```
$("#aroom").animate({ scrollTop: 300 }, "slow");
```

How would I return from a dialog into a particular location in a page?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/89fyf/

Comment: Thanks to alkis and Omar. Knowing $(document).on('pageshow'.. was the key, and storing the anchor= in the button was also what I needed.